Niko, Light of Hope and creature-land interaction
I have a question about how Niko, Light of Hope's ability interact with type-changing effects such as those from creature-lands.
If I animate ex. a Mutavault I can now exile it with Niko's ability, making all my Shards into Mutavaults that are just lands since the type-changing effect isn't copied. I can then animate my Shards (now Mutavaults) into land creatures. So far I understand, what I'm confused about is what happens during my end step.
Niko's ability stops at the beginning of my end step, but Mutavault's ability lasts until end of turn. So when my Shards go back to being Shards during the end step, will they still be land creatures due to Mutavaults ability, will they just be creatures since the base card is no longer a land, or will they switch to becoming enchantment creatures?

Your animated Shards will be 2/2 land creatures until the beginning of your end step, and afterwards 2/2 enchantment creatures until the end of turn.
Your shards start out as Shard enchantments.
After you've made them copies of Mutavault, they are Mutavault lands. They lose their enchantment type because Niko's effect overwrites it.
As you correctly note, you have to animate your shards separately after you've made them copies of Mutavault. When you do, this effect is added on top of Niko's and they are 2/2 Mutavault land creatures. The Mutavault animating effect does not grant them the land type, but lets them retain it from Niko's effect:

205.1b Some effects change an object’s card type, supertype, or subtype but specify that the object retains a prior card type, supertype, or subtype. In such cases, all the object’s prior card types, supertypes, and subtypes are retained. This rule applies to effects that use the phrase “in addition to its types” or that state that something is “still a [type, supertype, or subtype].”

At the beginning of your next end step, Niko's effect ends. Your Shards lose the land type but regain the enchantment type because it's  the Shard base characteristic and is no longer overwritten. In total, your Shards are now 2/2 enchantment creatures.
Finally, at the end of turn (meaning during the cleanup step), Mutavault's effect ends and your Shards return to their base type of enchantment only.

I think the key point here is that "It's still a land" actually means "It's still whatever types it was before (which under normal circumstances is Land)"
